# Why do I get UnsatisfiedLinkError when calling a MinGW-compiled function (not loading the library) on Windows?

Tags: java, c, windows, dll, java-native-interface

I'm making a simple JNI test app using Eclipse on Windows. My C++ compiler is MinGW 4.6.2. Java is throwing an `UnsatisfiedLinkError` when I try to invoke a function in my test DLL (the DLL itself loads without problem). I have verified that my DLL exports a "C" function with the same name as the function generated by the `javah` utility.

**How could trying to *invoke* the function possibly generate a link error?** (Also, is there any way to get more detail as to what symbol isn't being found? A bald statement that there's an `UnsatisfiedLinkError` is next to useless.)

#### Here's the Java which defines the native function:

```
package com.xyz.jsdi_test;

import java.io.File;

public class JSDI
{
    public static native void func(
        String str,
        int i,
        Integer ii,
        long j /* 64 bits */,
        Long jj,
        byte[] b
    );
    public static void dummy()
    {
        System.out.println("JSDI.dummy()");
    }
    static
    {
        File f = new File("..\\jsdi\\bin\\jsdi.dll");
        System.out.println("Preparing to load: " + f);
        System.load(f.getAbsolutePath());
        System.out.println("Successfully loaded: " + f);
    }
```

#### Here is the corresponding output from `javah`:

```
...
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     com_xyz_jsdi_test_JSDI
 * Method:    func
 * Signature: (Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/Integer;JLjava/lang/Long;[B)V
 */
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_xyz_jsdi_1test_JSDI_func
  (JNIEnv *, jclass, jstring, jint, jobject, jlong, jobject, jbyteArray);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

#### ...And how I implemented the function...:

```
extern "C"
{

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_xyz_jsdi_1test_JSDI_func(
    JNIEnv * env,
    jclass _class,
    jstring str,
    jint i,
    jobject ii,
    jlong j,
    jobject jj,
    jbyteArray b
)
{
    // don't do anything...let's just try to get called successfully...
}

} // extern "C"
```

#### Here is how I attempt to invoke it.

```
...

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    JSDI.dummy(); // cause class to load, which should cause System.load() to run.
    JSDI.func("hello", 0, 0, 0L, 0L, (byte[])null);
}
```

#### Finally, this is the output:

```
Preparing to load: ..\jsdi\bin\jsdi.dll
Successfully loaded: ..\jsdi\bin\jsdi.dll
JSDI.dummy()
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.xyz.jsdi_test.JSDI.func(Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/Integer;JLjava/lang/Long;[B)V
   at com.xyz.jsdi_test.JSDI.func(Native Method)
   at com.xyz.jsdi_test.SimpleTest.main(SimpleTest.java:24)
```

Comment: I've eliminated a couple of low-hanging fruit. It's not the underscore in the package name (note that `javah` wants to stick an '1' in front of it). Also I made a non-static member function taking zero arguments and get the same error when trying to call `new JSDI().mf();`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SOLVED IT -- WOOO!

It turns out that MSVC prepends an underscore to the name of `__stdcall` functions. MinGW does not. The Windows JVM apparently expects the '_' prefix. As soon as I prepended '_' to the function name and rebuilt with MinGW, everything worked just dandy.

*eg*:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_xyz_jsdi_1test_JSDI_func ==> _Java_com_xyz_jsdi_1test_JSDI_func
```

**EDIT**:
The `--add-stdcall-underscore` feature of the `dlltool` utility included with MinGW can solve  this problem for you transparently. Set it up in your Makefile and you don't need to worry about having different versions of the actual source code for different compilers. See [at this link](http://mingw.5.n7.nabble.com/work-around-msvc-compatible-stdcall-exports-td17487.html).

Answer (score 1):

Posting a working example, copy the content in the three files in the same directory (modify the path to your JDK) then invoke build.cmd

```
/* File: HelloWorld.java */
public class HelloWorld {
    private static native void writeHelloWorldToStdout();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.loadLibrary("HelloWorld");
        writeHelloWorldToStdout();
    }
}
```

---

```
/* File: HelloWorld.c */
#include <stdio.h>
#include "HelloWorld.h"
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_HelloWorld_writeHelloWorldToStdout(JNIEnv *env, jclass c)
{
    printf("Hello World!");
}
```

---

```
rem File: build.cmd 

%echo off
echo delete generated binaries
del HelloWorld.class
del HelloWorld.dll
del HelloWorld.h
del HelloWorld.def

echo Compile the Java Class
javac HelloWorld.java

echo Generate the Header file
javah -classpath . -o HelloWorld.h HelloWorld

echo Build the DLL 
gcc -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\include" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\include\win32" -Wl,--add-stdcall-alias -Wl,--output-def,HelloWorld.def -shared  -o HelloWorld.dll HelloWorld.c

echo run the program 
java HelloWorld
```

Comment: Thanks, in my case it helped adding `-Wl,--add-stdcall-alias`.

Answer (score 0):

The signature in the exception doesn't have the 'int' parameter. So your Java code disagrees with your native code.

Comment: Hmmm. I'm not sure where you're getting that. The 'I' indicates an `int` parameter. Furthermore, "C" calls don't have "signatures" *per se*, in the sense that the library doesn't export anything but the symbol name and it's up to the caller to know how to call it. So the most likely explanation is that the JVM can't find the symbol, rather than the JVM can't find a specific signature.