# JNI - java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError but right functions signatures

Tags: java, java-native-interface, unsatisfiedlinkerror

First, I'm using JDK 8 32bits with Eclipse 32bits.

I'm trying to figure out how to solve this error:

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError :

I checked signature's functions in C and package in JAVA but it looks right.

The complete error is :

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
>   fr.Model.initModel(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;[I)V

Java's function:

```
void initModel(String, String, String, int[]) in package fr and class Model
```

C function:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_fr_Model_initModel (JNIEnv  *, jobject, jstring, jstring, jstring, jintArray);
```

Launching it in a separate JVM but it does find the .dll. All dependencies checked, they are in system32.

Already doing the extern "C" { ... } trick to deal with C++.

Any ideas?

Comment: What compiler do you use? I seem to remember that at least for 64-bit DLLs you have to add some special option when you want to use the library with JNI. Maybe it's the same for 32-bit DLLs.

Comment: I'm using MinGW as i'm on Windows. It used to work someday and I didn't change anything to it so the options are prob right. Only thing that changed for compilation is upgrading from Java 6 to Java 8 but it doesn't change anything to the compilation process according to my researches.

Comment: You could try with Visual Studio anyway.

Comment: Is it going to change anything? Anyway I have to make a release and deploy it.on other machines, without any IDE so...

Comment: If something in the binary created by gcc is indeed the culprit, it might help. And of course you can deploy libraries built with Visual Studio on other machines. Even better: if you can use the version the JDK was built with (don't know, however, if that is available as a community edition) the user machines don't need the extra VC redistributable because the JDK has the needed VC runtime library

Comment: Found it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17199904/why-do-i-get-unsatisfiedlinkerror-when-calling-a-mingw-compiled-function-not-lo

Comment: Yup you found it ! Thank you !!